# Android distinguish between tap and double tap

Tags: android, android-gesture

I am using the `onTouch` method to catch a touch with `ACTION_UP` and `GestureDetector` to capture the double tap, my issue is a double tap results in a tap then a double tap, then a tap. Is there a way to have a double tap block a tap or something like that? I know logically what its doing is correct, so if you advise I find another way just comment, please dont down vote. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell what you might be doing wrong from just a description. Please show your code.

Comment: its not a code issue, the way a tap works is a ACTION_DOWN, and a ACTION_UP, so on a double tap you get two action ups and downs, so its working correctly but I was wondering if there is another way to distinguish single and double taps that does not result in two taps and a double tap at the same time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest that you switch to the [SimpleGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) and use the [onDoubleTap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onDoubleTap%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) and [onSingleTapConfirmed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onSingleTapConfirmed%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) methods.

Comment: Thats what I was looking for, ok I will look into that now! Thanks! I looked though the docs cant believe I didn't see that!

Comment: To be precise, it's the GestureDetector that does all the work, a SimpleGestureListener is just an implementation of GestureListener that always returns false.

Answer (score 3):

To be more precise than what is said by [britzl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16679961/910718), the `GestureDetector` does the actual work of determining when something is a single tap, double tap, long press, etc. The `SimpleGestureListener` is just a "listener" the `GestureDetector` uses to indicate what it recognized. It implements `OnGestureListener` and `OnDoubleTapListener` just to always return false. Check out a snippet from the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` in `GestureDetector`:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (mDoubleTapListener != null) {
            boolean hadTapMessage = mHandler.hasMessages(TAP);
            if (hadTapMessage) mHandler.removeMessages(TAP);
            if ((mCurrentDownEvent != null) && (mPreviousUpEvent != null) && hadTapMessage &&
                    isConsideredDoubleTap(mCurrentDownEvent, mPreviousUpEvent, ev)) {
                // This is a second tap
                mIsDoubleTapping = true;
                // Give a callback with the first tap of the double-tap
                handled |= mDoubleTapListener.onDoubleTap(mCurrentDownEvent);
                // Give a callback with down event of the double-tap
                handled |= mDoubleTapListener.onDoubleTapEvent(ev);
            } else {
                // This is a first tap
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(TAP, DOUBLE_TAP_TIMEOUT);
            }
        }

        mDownFocusX = mLastFocusX = focusX;
        mDownFocusY = mLastFocusY = focusY;
        if (mCurrentDownEvent != null) {
            mCurrentDownEvent.recycle();
        }
        mCurrentDownEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
        mAlwaysInTapRegion = true;
        mAlwaysInBiggerTapRegion = true;
        mStillDown = true;
        mInLongPress = false;
        mDeferConfirmSingleTap = false;

        if (mIsLongpressEnabled) {
            mHandler.removeMessages(LONG_PRESS);
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageAtTime(LONG_PRESS, mCurrentDownEvent.getDownTime()
                    + TAP_TIMEOUT + LONGPRESS_TIMEOUT);
        }
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageAtTime(SHOW_PRESS, mCurrentDownEvent.getDownTime() + TAP_TIMEOUT);
        handled |= mListener.onDown(ev);
        break;
```

Then **the desired result** can be obtained by creating a `GestureDetector` with the appropriate listener:

```
final View.OnTouchListener touch_listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                return _gesture_detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }

            private final GestureDetector _gesture_detector = new GestureDetector(getContext()
                    , new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                @Override public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO: implement single tap behavior
                    // NOTE: returning true indicates that the gesture was handled
                    return true;
                }

                @Override public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO: implement double tap behavior
                    // NOTE: returning true indicates that the gesture was handled
                    return true;
                }
            });
        };
```

And from there, this `OnTouchListener` can be set to the `View` that wants the behavior.

It works by using the default `GestureHandler` (which is a `Handler`):

```
private class GestureHandler extends Handler {
    GestureHandler() {
        super();
    }

    GestureHandler(Handler handler) {
        super(handler.getLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case SHOW_PRESS:
            mListener.onShowPress(mCurrentDownEvent);
            break;

        case LONG_PRESS:
            dispatchLongPress();
            break;

        case TAP:
            // If the user's finger is still down, do not count it as a tap
            if (mDoubleTapListener != null) {
                if (!mStillDown) {
                    mDoubleTapListener.onSingleTapConfirmed(mCurrentDownEvent);
                } else {
                    mDeferConfirmSingleTap = true;
                }
            }
            break;

        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknown message " + msg); //never
        }
    }
}
```

Recall the line `mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(TAP, DOUBLE_TAP_TIMEOUT);` from the `GestureDetector`. It delays notification of the tap by the timeout period for a valid double tap gesture. And the line `if (hadTapMessage) mHandler.removeMessages(TAP);` from the `GestureDetector` removes that notification upon a valid double tap. The `GestureHandler` receives the tap notification after the delay and uses the callback to notify the `GestureListener` with `mDoubleTapListener.onSingleTapConfirmed(mCurrentDownEvent);`. `GestureHandler` will delay that callback to the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` (handled by the `GestureDetector`) in the event that the user's finger is down when the tap notification is received.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what britzl suggests you may want to check your logic there for a second.

I don't think a double tap results in multiple, it simply results in 4 events, like you somewhat mention. While the Gesture libraries are (i think) the best choice, you should consider that:

- Store the Motionevent's timestamp (it's one of its methods) on ACTION_UP , then compare it with the next action up. Provided with a timeout, you will know when it is a tap or a double tap.

That is what the gesture listeners do